# Timestamp Decimal en Java

Tags: java, android, timestamp

Buenas noches a todos.

Necesito obtener el timestamp actual en formato decimal con la máxima precisión posible y a poder ser de una manera relativamente eficiente. Lo necesito para obtener medidas de red lo más realistas y precisas posibles.

Mi trabajo consiste en el envio de un tren de n paquetes y cada uno de esos n paquetes deben llevar un campo timestamp con su parte entera y decimal de 32 bits cada uno. Debido a esto, un etiquetado relativamente eficiente es importante. Sé que lo mejor sería programarlo en C pero lo necesito para un app Android y no tengo ni idea de Kotlin.

Os agradezco enormemente vuestra ayuda y tiempo.

Adjunto el código que llevo hecho relativa a la parte del timestamp:

```
DecimalFormat numberFormat = new DecimalFormat("#.0000");
ts2 = Instant.now();
d = (double) ts2.getEpochSecond() + (double) ts2.getNano() / 1000_000_000;
String[] ts = numberFormat.format(d).split(",");
```

Output Java:

```
1576974672,881
```

En python sin embargo obtengo mucha más precisión en el timestamp utilizando esta función:

```
"%.9f" % time.time()
```

Output Python:

```
1576950806.030862093
```

Comment: por favor, añade el código de lo que llevas :)

Comment: Acabo de adjuntarlo. Es lo máximo que he conseguido obtener pero es bastante lento este proceso.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Antes de todo es importante aclarar la nueva Date API incluída en java desde la versión 8 está implementada para trabajar con una precisión de nanosegundos.

El problema aquí viene dado por el hecho de que hasta la versión 8 la implementación del reloj por defecto en java solo brindaba una resolución a nivel de milisegundos. Esto da lugar a que al usar `Instant.now()` solo obtengamos una precisión de milisegundos porque el reloj que usa así lo limita.

A partir de Java 9, esto se mejoró. Ahora la implementación del reloj por defecto hace uso del reloj nativo subyacente del sistema operativo donde corre la JVM. En la mayoría de los sistemas esta puede ser de microsegundos o decenas de microsegundos.

Extracto de las notas de la liberación de esta mejora:

> "...In JDK 9, the implementation
>   is based on the underlying native clock that System.currentTimeMillis() is using, providing the maximum resolution available from that clock.
>   On most systems this can be microseconds, or sometimes even tenth of microseconds..."

[Aquí puedes encontrar el issue original](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8068730)

Por tales motivos, y teniendo en cuenta que has colocado la etiqueta `android`, lamento decirte que no vas  a lograr tener una mejor precisión ya que, hasta donde tengo entendido, la máquina virtual que se usa en Android ni siquiera soporta completamente Java 8.

Si por el contrario el código que muestras no lo ejecutas en Android, puedes utilizar una versión de Java superior a la 8 (te recomiendo la 11 que es LTS).

Con el siguiente código he obtenido estos resultados:

```
// Modifiqué el patrón para que muetre siempre 9 decimales
DecimalFormat format = new DecimalFormat("#.000000000");
Instant ts2 = Instant.now();
double d = (double) ts2.getEpochSecond() + (double) ts2.getNano() / 1_000_000_000;
System.out.println("Segundos: " + ts2.getEpochSecond());
System.out.println("Nanos: " + ts2.getNano());
System.out.println("Segundos y nanos: " + format.format(d));
```

```
// Salida 1
Segundos: 1577043360
Nanos: 510909000
Segundos y nanos: 1577043360.510909000
```

```
// Salida 2
Segundos: 1577043444
Nanos: 211842000
Segundos y nanos: 1577043444.211842000
```

Puedes ver que obtengo una precisión de microsegundos.

Mi entorno es este:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]